# How can i redirect user after login authentication in the home page?

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes, laravel-5.3

> In LoginController.php
>   I want to redirect user to home page.but it always shows blank page after authenticating user.

```
    public function authenticater($data,$request)
    {
        $email=$data['email'];
        $check=User::where('email', '=',$email)->first();
        //if not found means we need to register the user

        if ($check != null) {
            // Authentication passed.....
            $id=intval($check->id);
            Auth::loginUsingId($id,true);
            //echo '<html><script>setTimeout(function(){ window.history.go(-1); }, 3000);</script></html>';
            //echo '<html><script>location.href="/";</script></html>';

             return redirect()->guest(route('home'));

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,
**My mistake was: i called authenticater() from another method of controller.So,control was going to caller method.**

```
$this->authenticater($data,$request);
        return redirect('/home');
```

Solved. ..

anway,i tried all of that.still thank you @Jahid26 and @Iftikhar uddin :)

Answer (score 1):

Change  `return redirect()->guest(route('home'));` to

```
 return redirect('home');
```

OR

`return redirect()->route('home');`

And make sure that your `home.blade.php` has some data in there, other wise it will show blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You should write this

```
public function authenticater($data,$request)
    {
        $email=$data['email'];
        $check=User::where('email', '=',$email)->first();
        //if not found means we need to register the user

        if ($check != null) {
            // Authentication passed.....
            $id=intval($check->id);
            Auth::loginUsingId($id,true);
            //echo '<html><script>setTimeout(function(){ window.history.go(-1); }, 3000);</script></html>';
            //echo '<html><script>location.href="/";</script></html>';

             return redirect()->route('profile');

        }
```

This will solve your problem